# Where does git/ignore live?

Tags: git

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man5/gitignore.5.html

I'm trying to follow these directions, but when I go to my .config folder there's no git folder. I've used git many times already, but now I want to find the ignore file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.gitignore` file is a per project file and/or a per subdirectory file, located in the root directory of the project and/or various subdirectories of the project. For example, for my kernel git clone:

```
~/temp-k-git/linux$ ls -l -a .gitignore
-rw-rw-r-- 1 doug doug 1280 Jun 13 15:29 .gitignore
```

There are also 187 other .gitignore files in various subdirectories of the project.

Comment: According to the documentation it lives here: "   $HOME/.config/git/ignore"

I have a .git/info/exclude file (which I'm using, and works for my purposes for the time being), but there should be a way to set up git ignore rules for my machine (or that's what I'm understanding based on this documentation). I'm just not sure if there's something special I have to do to set that up as an Ubuntu user.

Comment: You can set global exclude files that would then apply to all repositories. You can configure git to use that file, for example `.gitignore_global`,  via (Note: I did not test it) `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`. If that is more what you were looking for, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I'm looking at this from the documentation: " Patterns which a user wants Git to ignore in all situations (e.g., backup or temporary files generated by the user’s editor of choice) generally go into a file specified by core.excludesFile in the user’s ~/.gitconfig. Its default value is $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is either not set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/ignore is used instead."

What does $XDG_CONFIG_HOME refer to?

Comment: According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Base_Directory_support $XDG_CONFIG_HOME defaults to HOME/.config. I have a HOME/.config folder but no git folder in there.

Comment: yes that's what I wound up doing.